# Is possible in the Orchestrator run two Processes?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot

I have Free Orchestrator version of UiPath, i want to know if there is a way to start a job in the orchestrator, when the job is still running for example at 08:00 P.M i have a second job scheduled that need to run.

Is possible to Stop the first job, run the second one and when the second job is finished start again with the first job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no sleep option available  so that you can not resume first transaction, kill , stop option available

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanic right now that has some priority features like you wish.

But there is a workaround that is working for you, although it's very static.

Workaround:

- Process A starts at e.g. 7:30
- Process A stops at 8:00 via `Stop Job` after `30 min`

[image: stop job]

- Process B starts at 8:00 and running until finishes
- Now start another Process A at 8:01
- That means when the Process B finishes, Process A will directly start

This will result in a high prio Process B.